# Simple VBA Vlookup Loop with Current Region reference

Tags: vba, excel, loops, vlookup

I have VB code that has a column of `LookupVals` and it succeeds at looking up the first value in the list, but I want it to keep going and Vlookup all of them -- and print the results in the cell below the first result.

Heres the encoding I have so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton4_Click()

LookupVal = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B16").Value
Range("A5").Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & LookupVal & ",Sheet2!" & Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A4").CurrentRegion.Address & _
",Sheet1!G13,FALSE)"

End Sub
```

The formula also incorporates a value held in a cell (G13, sheet 1) for the col_index_value.

Any help on looping this onto A6, A7, and so forth?

Comment: What's your lookup value for A6? It's not B16, right, because why would you need that formula twice?

Answer (score 0):

Loop the rows with a counter.  Using ("A" & lRow) instead of the hardcoded row ("A5").

```
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ws.Activate

    lRow = 5
    Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.count

        'Do your code here.

         LookupVal = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B16").Value
         ws.Range("A" & lRow).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & LookupVal & ",Sheet2!" &    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A4").CurrentRegion.Address & _
         ",Sheet1!G13,FALSE)"

        lRow = lRow + 1
        ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
    Loop
```

Comment: Thanks Matt, but how can this be modified so that I won't have to set 1Row equal to a definite number? I want to be able to run the same macro for sheets that have varying amount of rows in the lookupvalue column. Instead of a number, how would I write 1Row = "The number held  in cell G14" ?